# .Code to locate many same colored pixel but error says that there is an ambiguity

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\Images\\2.png',
             cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

x = 0
y = 0
n = 0

height = len(img)
width = len(img[0])

for row in range(height):
 for col in range(width):
    if img[row][col] == [0, 0, 0]:
        x = x + row
        y = y + col
        n = n + 1

        print n

cv2.imshow('image', img)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> error:
>        ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
>        ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score -1):

error give you an answer change your if statement

```
if img[row][col].all() == 0: #if all of the img[row][col]=0
```

Comment: That's not what that does.